# How to get the first instance of a mask if only it is in top N rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 9999, 100, 1, 954, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
    },
)
```

Expected output is creating column `c`:

```
      a      b       c
0   100   1000     NaN
1  1123  11123     NaN
2  9999   1123  9999.0
3   100      0     NaN
4     1     55     NaN
5   954      0     NaN
6     1      1     NaN
```

The mask is:

```
mask = ((df.a > df.b))
```

I want to get the first row that meets the conditions of this mask IF ONLY it is in top 3 rows and put `df.a` to create `c`. For this example this code works:

```
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'c'] = df.a
```

But for this DataFrame it should return `NaN` for `c` because the first instance of `mask` is not in top 3 rows. But it does not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 954, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to the mask based on the index:

```
mask = (df.a > df.b) & (df.index < 3)
```

For your second example, this will result in:

```
     a      b   c
0    0   1000 NaN
1    0  11123 NaN
2    0   1123 NaN
3    0      0 NaN
4    0     55 NaN
5  954      0 NaN
6    1      1 NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want column `c` to come out exactly as in your question, then you can use the following code:

```
mask = ((df.a > df.b) & (df.index < 3))
df["c"] = df.a[mask]
```

When `df.a[mask]` is broadcast in the last line, it will put NaNs in all rows where the mask evaluates to False. So, this results in:

```
      a      b       c
0   100   1000     NaN
1  1123  11123     NaN
2  9999   1123  9999.0
3   100      0     NaN
4     1     55     NaN
5   954      0     NaN
6     1      1     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to compute another mask, just slice `df['a']` and reindexing will occur during assignment:

```
mask = df['a'] > df['b']

df.loc[mask, 'c'] = df['a'].iloc[:3]
```

Output:

```
# example 1
      a      b       c
0   100   1000     NaN
1  1123  11123     NaN
2  9999   1123  9999.0
3   100      0     NaN
4     1     55     NaN
5   954      0     NaN
6     1      1     NaN

# example 2
     a      b   c
0    0   1000 NaN
1    0  11123 NaN
2    0   1123 NaN
3    0      0 NaN
4    0     55 NaN
5  954      0 NaN
6    1      1 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you check my other post? I posted it a couple minutes ago.

Comment: @x_Amir_x sure, I answered

Comment: For this `df `, I only want the first row. `df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 9999, 100, 1, 954, 1],
        'b': [1, 1, 1, 0, 55, 0, 1],
    },    
)`. I think my question was not clear enough. This one works `mask = (df.a > df.b) & (df.index < 3)`